# understanding librosa.feature.spectral_contrast

Tags: python, librosa

i am using python and
I am trying to use this function but i am struggling with it.

[image: See code error]

```
  def extract_feature_for_one_signal(signal):
    signal = signal.astype(float)
    mel = np.mean(librosa.feature.melspectrogram(signal, sr=SAMPLE_RATE, n_fft=N_FFT, hop_length=HOP_LENGTH).T, axis=0)
    mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=signal, sr=SAMPLE_RATE, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
    stft = np.abs(librosa.stft(signal))
    chroma = np.mean(librosa.feature.chroma_stft(S=stft, sr=SAMPLE_RATE).T, axis=0)
    **contrast = np.mean(librosa.feature.spectral_contrast(S=stft, sr=SAMPLE_RATE).T, axis=0)**
    tonnetz = np.mean(librosa.feature.tonnetz(y=librosa.effects.harmonic(signal), sr=SAMPLE_RATE).T, axis=0)
    average_distance = []
    for std in STD_NUMS:
        average_distance.append(average_distance_between_spikes(np.abs(signal), std, 320))
        average_distance.append(average_distance_between_spikes(signal, std, 320))
    return mfccs, chroma, mel, contrast, tonnetz, average_distance
```

The program falls here:

```
    contrast = np.mean(librosa.feature.spectral_contrast(S=stft, sr=SAMPLE_RATE).T, axis=0)

SAMPLE_RATE = 1000 (it must be 1000.....)
```

what can i do to make it work?

Comment: the bug is; raise ParameterError('Frequency band exceeds Nyquist. Reduce either fmin or n_bands)

Comment: Why must the sample rate be 1000? That is incredibly low for audio (what librosa is typically for)

Answer (score 0):

Your nyquist is would be greater than the sampling rate. Try redcuing the number of filter band from default 6 to maybe 3 or 4. You can also reduce your fmin to say 50.

The sampling rate you have choosen is too small. Keep it around 44100, which is the standard. It should work fine then